# gatsbyJS: error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'react_1'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I'm trying to integrate typescript with custom routes in gatsbyjs as followed:

```
require("source-map-support").install();
require("ts-node").register();

exports.createPages = require("./src/createPages");
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017"],
    // "allowJs": true,
    // "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

gastby-config.js

```
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/templates`,
        name: "markdown-pages"
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-svg`
  ]
};
```

but when i try to import custom routes located in the **routes** folder i get the following error:

`src/Layout.tsx(6,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'react_1'.`

For the routes i use

```
import Index from "../pages";

const routes = {
  home: {
    path: "/",
    component: Index
  }

};

// Same keys as 'routes', but the value is only the path.
const paths = Object.keys(routes).reduce((acc, route) => {
  acc[route] = routes[route].path;
  return acc;
}, {});

export { routes, paths };
```

and the createPages consists out of:

```
import { routes } from "./routing";

const createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  Object.keys(routes).forEach(route => createPage(routes[route]));
};

export default createPages;
```

Layout.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";
import "./scss/style.scss";
import "./logo.css";

const Layout: React.SFC<any> = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {props.children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

As i'm rather new to gatsby i've followed https://dev.to/hugecoderguy/routing-with-gatsby-and-react-4dlh to integrate the routing. but this combined with typescript seems to be giving some typescript errors. any ideas on this?

Comment: You did not post the `Layout.tsx` file if i'm following correctly. It seems to be the redeclaration of an import which leads to this conflict. `react_1` is probably the alias generated by an import, whether using the es6 module or the commonjs spec that conflict with another declaration.

Comment: Thank you, i have added layout.tsx. my tsconfig is using commonjs

Answer (score 1):

Fixed is as followed:

- changed the components as followed: `resolve(__dirname, "../components/pages/IndexPage.tsx")`
- tsconfig to:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Hopefully it helps someone in the future.

Comment: Nice, did you find out what causes the issue in the first place & why this fix works?

Comment: well, before i used `import IndexPage from ...` and used that component under the routes. now i changed it to `resolve(...)` which fixed it. I'm guessing because it imported the file and ts-node transpiled it to a js (which was already transpiled to a js file before because i used the typescript plugin of gatsby)